# Mail Sending Script

Tags: php

```
///Send mail to members whom subscribed to receive mail

$one = 1;
settype($one, 'integer');

$two = 2;
settype($two, 'integer');

$query_news_mail = "SELECT M.id, M.j_email, M.j_news_alert, M.j_news_catid_notification FROM jt_members M WHERE (M.j_news_alert = $two AND M.j_news_catid_notification = $data[catid]) AND M.j_news_alert = $one;";
$mail_result = mysql_query($query_news_mail) or die(trigger_error(MYSQL_ERROR_MSG,E_USER_ERROR));

while($row_mail = mysql_fetch_assoc($mail_result)) {


//start sending mails here
echo "mail";
}
```

The second clause does not execute //M.j_news_alert = $one
Any ides?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you meant

```
... notice the OR in place of AND ...
(M.j_news_alert = $two AND M.j_news_catid_notification = $data[catid]) OR M.j_news_alert = $one;
```

Otherwise you cannot meet your WHERE condition: `M.j_news_alert = $two AND M.j_news_alert = $one;`

Answer (score 0):

```
(M.j_news_alert = $two AND M.j_news_catid_notification = $data[catid])
AND M.j_news_alert = $one;
```

This can never be `true`, so you end up with an empty result set.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT M.id, M.j_email, M.j_news_alert, M.j_news_catid_notification 
FROM jt_members M
WHERE (M.j_news_alert = $two AND M.j_news_catid_notification = $data[catid]) OR M.j_news_alert = $one;"

Yeah, I think you need and mean OR

EDIT: Looks like someone beat me to it.